# Filtering error when using custom Varien object collection in admin grid

Tags: model, collection, varien

I have created a custom Varien object collection for my admin module (because the data is not from a db) and have got it successfully to show in an admin grid. I built the collection by using the following code:

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
```

Inside loop:

```
$object = new Varien_Object();
$object->setFileName($filename);
$collection->addItem($object);
```

It's all working perfectly except when I try to filter using the grid filtering system, it returns this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Varien_Data_Collection::addFieldToFilter() in /data/www/vhosts/adammoss.co.uk/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php on line 472

I know that `addFieldToFilter()` is only used on EAV objects, which my collection obviously has none of. My question is whether anybody knows of any way around this?

Can I append that method to my object in some way or would I have to create a model for this to work?

******UPDATE 08/02/2012 ******

OK, so I've slightly changed the way I do this. I'm still using my custom class which is an exact duplicate of `Filesystem.php`

My grid collection now looks like this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = new MyNamespace_MyModule_Model_Csv_Collection();
    $collection->addTargetDir('my/target/path');
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

It loads in all my Files into the grid as expected, and it now Paginates! However for some reason it still won't filter or sort, even though I'm literally just using the exact same class as `Filesystem.php`.

I'll check `Mage_Backup` class as you suggested.

Comment: If someone ever needs to implement that for non file collections, here's how I did it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124171/magento-1-filtering-paging-sorting-with-varien-data-collection/124324#124324

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem not in EAV based entities. Method `addFieldToFilter()` is available only in `Varien_Data_Db_Collection`, that EAV and standard ORM models extend. If you'd like to have your admin grid module working with your collection in the same way as it works with DB collection, you need to implement two methods:

- `addFieldToFilter($filterName, $conditionArray)`
- `setSort($fieldName, $direction)`

Example of such custom collection implementation you can find in `Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem` class that utilizes FS based collections. This kind of collection, for instance, used in `Mage_Backup` module to show grid with backup files.

Sincerely, 
Ivan

Comment: Great response, thank you. Can I ask where I'd implement the methods as I've not created any class for my object?

Comment: @AdamMoss You need to create a new collection class extended from `Varien_Data_Collection`. You don't need to specify anything in your model, just make sure that your collection filters out data correctly.

Comment: Ok done that and the error's gone which is great, but it's not actually filtering. Is it because these methods aren't built for this specific object collection?

Comment: @AdamMoss Take a look at Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem, how it filters data.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I've been playing around with this endlessly - the collection does not filter, sort or page at all in the grid. Is it possible that this type of collection is simply not compatible with an admin grid?

Comment: @AdamMoss Do you implement your custom logic on collection logic or you are adding items to it without using of load method?

Comment: I've updated my original post - gonna have a look at Mage_Backup - if you have any further suggestion/help it would be much appreciated! Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: If someone ever needs to implement that for non file collections, here's how I did it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124171/magento-1-filtering-paging-sorting-with-varien-data-collection/124324#124324