# How to implement this code to sort the grid in admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, sorting

I want to "naturally" sort skus in admin panel ("grid"?) and I found this code: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124324/51693 which would be exactly what I need, but I don't know where to call this class or how to implement it. If someone could, at least, point me in the right direction, that would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To add any default sorting for the Magento admin Grid. We just need to add below line in the `prepareCollection` method of that **Grid.php**

```
$this->setDefaultSort('sku'); /*whatever column you need as default sort you can use*/
```

Comment: That would change the default sorting attribute for the admin grid, but how do I implement this (http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124324/51693) code so that Magento uses it for the sorting? Sorry if my question wasn't clear. Thank you!