# How is admin grid sorted?

Tags: magento-1.7, grid, sorting

I want to add "natural sorting" functionality to Magento admin grid. I would like to understand how the Magento handles admin grid sorting so I know where to start. What functions/files etc. does Magento use to determine the order of values in the admin panel?

Comment: will you please explain more

Comment: I want to add a functionality like "natsort" in PHP, to admin panel sorting (catalog, sales, etc.) . There is very little info about this online. I found this code that in theory should help me: (http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124324/51693), but I do not understand how to implement it.

Comment: _build_sorter function, to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With grids in Magento, the database driver controls the sorting of data.  The collection is passed the sort column and direction of sort (asc or desc) or the default is used.  The data in the collection returned is output in that same order.

To change the sorting functionality in your own custom grid, you can just alter modify the `_prepareCollection` method to adjust the collection to what order you want.

In my custom grid, I would probably do something like this:

```
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Index_Grid extends Mage_Core_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    // ...

    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $myCollection = Mage::getModel('my_module/model')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($myCollection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    // ...

    protected function _afterLoadCollection() {
        usort($this->_collection, array($this, '_natSortCollection'));
        return parent::_afterLoadCollection();
    }

    protected function _natSortCollection($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a->getField(), $b->getField());
    }
}
```

### Edit

See the updated code below to do what you want.

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $items = $this->_collection->getItems();
    /* To prevent duplicate items, and to not reload from the database
       we have to remove each item individually without "clear()"ing
       the collection. */
    array_walk(array_keys($items), array($this->_collection, 'removeItemByKey'));
    usort($items, array($this, '_natSortCollection'));

    /* Now add each item back to the collection in the new order */
    array_walk($items, array($this->_collection, 'addItem'));
    return parent::_afterLoadCollection();
}

protected function _natSortCollection($itemA, $itemB)
{
    return strnatcmp($itemA->getName(), $itemB->getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your example code is for a custom module. What changes are needed so that I could put it straight in the: \core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php ?

Comment: Currently I am getting an error... I am replacing 'my_module/model' with 'catalog/product'.

Comment: The above code was only meant to guide you, not be a full-fledged working example.  I would never suggest you overwrite the core files, even temporarily for testing purposes.  For the `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php` file, you should only have to add the `_afterLoadCollection` and `_natSortCollection` methods.  Without knowing the error you're running in to, I won't be able to help much

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. I have to add `_afterLoadCollection` and `_natSortCollection` in `Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php` . Should I also make some changes in `_prepareCollection` function? 
And what do you mean by "adding `_afterLoadCollection` and `_natSortCollection` methods" to `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`? Sorry, I'm a Magento novice.

Comment: The core grid already has the `_prepareCollection` method so you don't need to add that.  The `_afterLoadCollection` should be being called automatically.  I would check the parent of the grid and make sure there is a reference to a call to `_afterLoadCollection` in it; otherwise, it won't work (but the feature exists in 1.9).

Comment: This makes so much more sense now. The problem is that I'm still using 1.7. Could you perhaps instruct me on how to add the reference to the parent? `class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget` from this I would Imagine the parent is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget` right? Or by the parent you mean something else? Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure I have a 1.7 code-base lying around anywhere anymore.  Let me see if I can dig one up.

Comment: That would be amazing!

Comment: Just downloaded Magento 1.7.0.2.  `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid` extends `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid`.  The `_prepareCollection` method calls `parent::_prepareCollection` at the end which  will call `_afterLoadCollection`.  If you add the `_afterLoadCollection` method to the  `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid` it should execute.  My guess here is that the collection is ignoring the reordering of items.  Instead, you may need to create a new `Varien_Data_Collection` and manually add the items in the order you want.

Comment: So I just edited my post with another code snippet that works in Magento 1.9 and should work in Magento 1.7.  Hope it helps.

Comment: You are my HERO! The new snippet works! Except it doesn't let me change the sorting direction (ASC, DESC) when clicking on the attribute. But this is a great progress! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From your comments in the previous answer, it may behoove you to use the MySQL `SOUNDEX(<column_name>)` function to naturally sort your data.  You can even then add a `LENGTH(<column_name>)` call and finally `<column_name>`.  For example:

```
    $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf(
            'SOUNDEX(%1$s) %2$s, LENGTH(%1$s) %2$s, %1$s %2$s',
            $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort),
            $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir)
        )
    ));
```

This isn't perfect, but there isn't "natural sorting" in MySQL.  So it's kind of as close as you can get to it.  Using a separate method to alter the collection would add a layer of complexity and require work-arounds to make changing the sort column and direction to work 100% of the time.

This is just an alternative to the custom sort method above.

Comment: Hmm, either I'm implementing it wrong or it doesn't seem to be working, although I admit that I was not able to fully wrap my head around how the SOUNDEX and LENGHT together would create something similar to natsort.
Currently I'm placing the code at the very end of `_prepareCollection()` right after the `$this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();` that was already there.

Comment: That's where I had that code and it worked for me.  Basically `SOUNDEX()` orders it alphabetically, then the `LENGTH()` is there to help with things with numbers after them (e.g. "Random String 1", "Random String 2", "Random String 11") and finally it sorts it as it normally would.  So instead of getting "Random String 1", "Random String 11", "Random String 2", you get a properly ordered list.

Comment: Really odd, I must be doing something wrong then... Is this how it is supposed to look like [link](http://imgur.com/HVEbRH3) ? just to be sure- this is the only edit needed for this method to work, right?

Comment: Yeah, that should be all that's necessary.  It's what I did and it worked.

Comment: Is it possible that I am missing something in the `Zend_Db_Expr`?

Comment: Not sure.  Zend_Db_Expr has been pretty standard and unchanged for a while.  Try printing out the SQL and running it on your own on the database.  This line will print it for you: echo '<pre>' . $this->getCollection()->getSelect() . '</pre>';

Comment: Interesting, it works as intended when ran on the database... But doesn't use the same order for the admin panel in Magento for some reason.

Comment: Sounds like something might be overriding the product list grid.

Comment: I would also think so, except for this i'm using a completely fresh magento install and the only edit I've made is this one...

Comment: Maybe the sorting is applied to collection after It's loaded already?